# Removing space b/w two divs

Tags: html, css

I don't have any margin-bottom's in my div's but there seems to be a thing that separating them. 
There is a gap between DivId wrapper and DivId footer ^o) I tried display:inline-block and line-height:0 but none helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You positioned #nobe relatively - you moved the contents up, but the container's size didn't change.

For example - if you have a 100x100 div and set style="position:relative; top:-50px;" to any div that resides inside of the container, then the contents will move up for 50px, but container's size will still be 100x100, so other elements will treat it as 100x100 block (not 100x50) and position themselves under a 100x100 block.